# CSS rule to style first list item

Tags: css

I'm attempting to get a CSS style to apply to the top list item but can't get the rules to apply in the desired fashion. In the example below I'm trying to remove the top border for the very first `li` item. It works if I put `style="border-top: none;"` inline on the locationMenuTopItem element but I need to do it with a style block.

Why is the `#locationMenu li` block overruling the `#locationMenuTopItem` block?

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 #locationMenu li {
    border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;    
}

#locationMenuTopItem {
   border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="locationMenu">
     <li id="locationMenuTopItem"><a href="#">Top Menu</a>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Top Menu 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Top Menu 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [CSS specificity](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity) - the selector `#locationMenu li` is more *specific* than `#locationMenuTopItem`. Using `#locationMenu #locationMenuTopItem` will work here.

Here's a graphical guide from Andy Clarke that will help: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: Thx for the link. That cleared it up. I did read the W3C link prior to asking but it was a too late in the day to decipher it.

Answer (score 14):

> Why is the "#locationMenu li" block overruling the #locationMenuTopItem block?

It is more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

```
#locationMenu > li:first-child
```

should do the job without having to add additional ids. (Although not in IE6)

Answer (score 5):

This could be a possible answer:

```
#locationMenu li,
#locationMenu li:first-child ul li
{
    border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;    
}

#locationMenu li:first-child
{
    border-top:none;
}
```

It is overrulie, because the #locationMenu li is deeper than #locationMenuTopItem alone. The more statements in a row, the deeper it is.